# setting $ENV{variable} when calling python

Tags: python, env

I'm new to Python and would like reproduce a convenience I used when working in Perl.
When calling a Perl script I usually set some $ENV variables (like VERBOSE, DEVELOP and DEBUG). Inside the called script I recover their values using

```
my $verbose=$ENV{VERBOSE};
my $develop=$ENV{DEVELOP};
my $debug=$ENV{DEBUG};
```

This allow print stmts conditional on these variables.

Can I do the same thing in Python? I know thanks to previous responses (Thank you!) to use os.environ[var] within the script to access the values. But I have not been able to figure out how to assign a value to a variable when I call the script from the command line as I could when callinbg a Perl script

Can values be set for such variables on the commandline invoking a python script?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

They are accessible via the [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) dictionary.

```
os.environ['VERBOSE']
```